# Colnames and row names disappearing when I use cat in a return with a matrix

Tags: r, function, matrix, statistics, return

I'm learning R and we have to build a function taking a continuous variable, a categorical variable and a title in order to return basics statistics on the continous variable (`mean`, `sd`, `median`, `max`, `min`) all of it organised by category of the categorical variable. At the end, the function should return the title we inserted in the argument followed by the matrix.

My probleme is that I get the matrix and everything fine until I add the title and the separation row that my teacher wants. When I do so, the matrix get disorganized and the row and col names disappear.

I tried specifying the `dimnames` (I created a list not shown on the code below) and specifying the return as a matrix. I also tried to use different ways to print the title but at the end, it always destroys the matrix.
I understand it probably have something to do with the variable type but I don't have the level to fix it and my work is in a week and I'm deadly stuck at this part.

If you remove all the `cat` part in return, you get the matrix wanted but without the title.

```
stat.descriptive<-function(var.cont,var.desc,titre){
  #calcul des stats descriptives selon les catégories
  Moyenne<-round(by(var.cont,var.desc,mean,na.rm=TRUE),2);
  Ecart_type<-round(by(var.cont,var.desc,sd,na.rm=TRUE),2);
  Mediane<-round(by(var.cont,var.desc,median,na.rm=TRUE),2);
  Minimum<-round(by(var.cont,var.desc,min,na.rm=TRUE),2);
  Maximum<-round(by(var.cont,var.desc,max,na.rm=TRUE),2);
  #nommer les lignes et colonnes : 
  stat.des.noms<-c("Moyenne","Ecart-type","Mediane","Minimum","Maximum");
  #mise en forme du retour
  return(c(cat(titre,"\n"),
           cat("-----------------------------------------------","\n"),
           as.matrix(cbind(Moyenne,Ecart_type,Mediane,Minimum,Maximum),dimnames(a))))
}
```

Comment: So it is not possible to return this as a list? I mean `return(list(title = title,
matrix = as.matrix(cbind(Moyenne,Ecart_type,Mediane,Minimum,Maximum),dimnames(a))))`? I'm thinking about this "title we inserted in the argument followed by the matrix" and what does it mean exactly. Also, you don't need to use `return()` if you want to return the last object.

Comment: i thought to do it at first but we have to use invible in the answer apparently. i modified it to obtain ` return(c( `
           ` cat(titre,"\n"),`
            cat("--------------------------------"),
            print(as.matrix(cbind(Moyenne,Ecart_type,Mediane,Minimum,Maximum)))
        ) ) ``` but now I get the title followed by the matrix and then the data of the matrix but as a list. I would like to delete that final list of the report. I know it's not the most efficient way to do it but that's my instructions :(

Comment: the" ` " in my code are me trying to highlight my code as a code in the comment and not a real part of my code (i m new to stackoverflow sry)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `print` in the last line of printing the matrix in `return`, as `cat` prints the matrix as one line not a square. I also changed a series of `by` into one `sapply` to avoid the code quantuplication. Additionally I used `invisible` instead of `return` otherwise output will be doubled. Finally `cat` does not return any value. See the code below:

```
stat.descriptive <- function(var.cont, var.desc, titre){
  #calcul des stats descriptives selon les catégories
  funcs <- c(mean, sd, median, min, max)
  res <- sapply(funcs, function(x) round(by(var.cont, var.desc, x, na.rm = TRUE)))
  colnames(res) <- c("Moyenne", "Ecart-type", "Mediane", "Minimum", "Maximum")
  
  cat(titre,"\n")
  cat("-----------------------------------------------\n")
  print(res)
  invisible(res)
}

stat.descriptive(1:10, rep(letters[1:2], 5), "Mes stats")
```

Output:

```
Mes stats
-----------------------------------------------
  Moyenne Ecart-type Mediane Minimum Maximum
a       5          3       5       1       9
b       6          3       6       2      10
```